# Problem with NVIDIA drivers and encrypted partition (dual boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 but I have problems when I boot up.

My machine has 2 SSDs:

- First one with Windows 10
- Second one with Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 (on which I boot)

I installed an encrypted Ubuntu with LVM on the SSD.
When I booted everything went fine but after going to "additional drivers", and restarting, I get a black screen.

I tried typing my password to decrypt my partition but nothing happens.

Things I tried:

- CTRL + ALT + F1 (tried to put "nomodeset" into /etc/defaults/grub") but I can't get the prompt.
- I also tried to press "E" when the grub screen appears and to put "nomodeset" after "quiet splash"
- I tried a regular Ubuntu 16.04 and check the disks

My graphic card is a GTX 780.

Is there something I missed ?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to remove the `quiet splash` part to get some visual feedback.

Comment: I tried... It doesn't fix the problem, unfortunately

Comment: Apparently I'm not the only one, some people fixed the problem by disabling secure boot (I did it too) but the problem is stil the same..

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem so I gave up ubuntu splash in favor of working boot.
You can:

1. Edit /etc/default/grub replacing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"`
2. before reboot call `sudo update-grub` from terminal